# How to avoid gaps between bars of histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I encountered many similar situations like the following one. I am trying to create a simple histogram like so:

```
coins.2 <- c(-2,0,0,2)
hist(coins.2,freq=F)
```

The result is this:

[image]

**My question**
What is the easiest way to draw the histogram without gaps between the bars?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of, is to summarise the results using table and then plot that summary:

`barplot(table(coins.2))`

or if you wanted to stick to the density output, divide the summary by the total number of observations

```
barplot(table(coins.2)/length(coins.2))
```

But please remember that there is a reason for histogram showing that empty space. If these were nominal categories, it would not be much of a problem, but if these are actual values it's best to use the histogram solution and show the empty space.

Comment: The issue here is that the values are discrete, but the `hist` function treats them as continuous. There aren't any values between the integers. I think the best solution here is a discrete histogram that goes from -2 to 2, with bars centered over each integer value, and with "bars" of zero height (empty spaces) at -1 and 1. In this case, something like `coins.2 = factor(c(-2,0,0,2), levels=seq(-2,2,1))
barplot(table(coins.2))`

Comment: Another option to center the bars over each integer value without creating factors is `hist(coins.2, breaks=seq(-2.5,2.5,1))`.